# Remove rows by duplicate column(s) values

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have a large dataset in a `numpy.ndarray` similar to this:

```
array([[ -4,   5,   9,  30,  50,  80],
       [  2,  -6,   9,  34,  12,   7],
       [ -4,   5,   9,  98, -21,  80],
       [  5,  -9,   0,  32,  18,   0]])
```

I would like to remove duplicate rows, where the 0th, 1st, 2nd and 5th columns are equal. I.e. On the above matrix, the response would be:

```
-4, 5, 9, 30, 50, 80
2, -6, 9, 34, 12, 7
5, -9, 0, 32, 18, 0
```

`numpy.unique` does something very similar but it only finds duplicates over all columns (axis). I only want specific columns. How would one get around to do this with `numpy`? I could not find any decent `numpy` algorithm to do this. Is there a better module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) on the sliced array with `return_index` param over `axis=0`, that gives us unique indices, considering each row as one entity. These indices could be then used for row-indexing into the original array for the desired output.

So, with `a` as the input array, it would be -

```
a[np.unique(a[:,[0,1,2,5]],return_index=True,axis=0)[1]]
```

Sample run to break down the steps and hopefully make things clear -

```
In [29]: a
Out[29]: 
array([[ -4,   5,   9,  30,  50,  80],
       [  2,  -6,   9,  34,  12,   7],
       [ -4,   5,   9,  98, -21,  80],
       [  5,  -9,   0,  32,  18,   0]])

In [30]: a_slice = a[:,[0,1,2,5]]

In [31]: _, unq_row_indices = np.unique(a_slice,return_index=True,axis=0)

In [32]: final_output = a[unq_row_indices]

In [33]: final_output
Out[33]: 
array([[-4,  5,  9, 30, 50, 80],
       [ 2, -6,  9, 34, 12,  7],
       [ 5, -9,  0, 32, 18,  0]])
```

Comment: @Divakar this worked great thanks. I dont understand a couple of things though.  `return_index` is supposed to return another row at the end right? how come this doesn't return it? does it have to do witht he final `[1]` cause I don't understand what it is doing there.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that `_,` goes to the last ndarray. what is that commad called? I would like to search it a bit more.

Comment: @user7331538 `_` is just a placeholder to skip storing as an output variable. That's why `np.unique(a_slice,return_index=True,axis=0)[1]` works as well as it gets the second output directly.

Answer (score 2):

Pandas has functionality for this via [`pd.DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html). However, the convenient syntax comes at the cost of performance.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[ -4,   5,   9,  30,  50,  80],
              [  2,  -6,   9,  34,  12,   7],
              [ -4,   5,   9,  98, -21,  80],
              [  5,  -9,   0,  32,  18,   0]])

res = pd.DataFrame(A)\
        .drop_duplicates(subset=[0, 1, 2, 5])\
        .values

print(res)

array([[-4,  5,  9, 30, 50, 80],
       [ 2, -6,  9, 34, 12,  7],
       [ 5, -9,  0, 32, 18,  0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `np.take` method (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) to get the only the columns from the array that you care about and then use the unique method with `return_index=True`.

```
>>> arr = np.array([[ -4,   5,   9,  30,  50,  80],
...        [  2,  -6,   9,  34,  12,   7],
...        [ -4,   5,   9,  98, -21,  80],
...        [  5,  -9,   0,  32,  18,   0]])
>>> relevant_columns = np.take(arr, [0,1,2,5], axis=1)
>>> np.unique(relevant_columns, axis=0, return_index=True)
(array([[ 2, -6,  9,  7],
       [ 5, -9,  0,  0],
       [-4,  5,  9, 80]]), array([1, 3, 0]))
```

You can then use `np.take()` again with your original numpy array. Pass `array([1, 3, 0])` as the parameter for the indices.